# A particular image is not getting any response from server (15 of 20 images have uploaded) in WCF multipart data image from android

Tags: c#, wcf

I am Receiving images from android in WCF service, In form of multipart data, I am able to receive most of the images, but particular image gets no response, it does not enter the method itself.(server does not take that request).

```
when checked in postman,

Could not get any response
```

I have increased all bindings, webHttpBinding sizes to 2147483647, connection time out increased in server.

// method to receive images from android

```
public Stream Savephotos(Stream stream)
        {}
```

I added trace and found that, this particular image is not entering this method:- public Stream Savephotos(Stream stream), And its throwing System.IO.IOException An exception has been thrown when reading the stream.

I expect a solution. either its on server (config file) or on code, or android

Comment: I added trace and found that, this particular image is not entering this method:- public Stream Savephotos(Stream stream), And its throwing System.IO.IOException An exception has been thrown when reading the stream.